# Webkit: CSS3 2D transform Scale + cubic bezier issue (when argument > 1)

Tags: css, webkit, css-transitions, css-transforms

I wanted to create a "bouncy" animation for an element using:

```
div{

  -webkit-transform:scale(0);
  -moz-transform:scale(0);
  -ms-transform:scale(0);

  -webkit-transition:all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.57, 0.07, 0.44, 2);
  -moz-transition:all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.57, 0.07, 0.44, 2);
  -ms-transition:all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.57, 0.07, 0.44, 2);
}
div.fire{

  -webkit-transform:scale(1);
  -moz-transform:scale(1);
  -ms-transform:scale(1);
}
```

Fairly simple. Using the scale transform, I hide the element completely (or scale it down to whatever I want). Then I assign a transition property using cubic-bezier with the last argument 2 (see the curve here: http://cubic-bezier.com/#.57,.07,.44,2 )

Then, on a second stage (could be on hover or activated by something else, I get the 'fired' class) I scale it up to 100%.

The expected behaviour using `cubic-bezier()` would be that the `scale()` property grows past 1 and then comes back to 1, creating a "bounce" effect. This works for other properties (such as `padding`, `left`, `margin`) but not for the scale transform.

This doesn't happen on Chrome (28.0.1500.71 m, Windows 7 64bit).
Wokrs OK on Firefox and IE10

See example here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oiexl

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working fine with the current Chrome Canary build 30.0.1561.0, so it looks like it's this bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=178299 It causes the value to get clamped between `0` and `1` for transforms.

There doesn't seem to be a workaround, other than using precalculated animations. Try for example http://www.css3animationgenerator.com/

Comment: Thank you. It's really weird because this bug report: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45761 was reported in 2010-09, then fixed, now the bug is back and fixed again?

Comment: I can't tell for sure, but it looks like that old webkit bug only affected the CSS parser, while this new problem affects [the calculation of the actual value](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=178070#c13) in the graphics engine.