# translateX together with transition-timing-function not working in chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation, css-transitions

I animate an element using the `translateX()` property, together with a `transition-timing-function`. But it seems that the timing function is not applied? When i use transition of `left: xx` instead it works.

But as translate uses the GPU its much faster, so i would like to use this instead. Any ideas why is that?

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem in a Fiddle?

Comment: Also OS, Browser and/or Device specific? And just in case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582498/webkit-css3-2d-transform-scale-cubic-bezier-issue-when-argument-1

Comment: i created a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/S9qTu/) and it seems to work, now i confused. i will check what i did wrong and report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is chrome.
It seems to be not implemented for translate in chrome.
Check the jsfiddle here in the comments.

works in safari, but not chrome.